# how to save generated xcode project as artifact

Tags: ios, cordova, bitrise

Currently we have a setup in bitrise that builds .ipa files and saves them as artifact (and deploys to app store connect)

Is there a way to save the intermediate xCode project generated by cordova as an artifact (.zip file or whatever)?

Answer (score 1):

If you exactly know the path to that file and you have `Deploy to Bitrise.io` step in your workflow you can add that files. It's described in [Bitrise docs](https://devcenter.bitrise.io/tips-and-tricks/attach-any-file-to-build/).